# MVC: after add a row through ajax, new value doesn't pass to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying use MVC to write a simple page showing a legend definition for a specific event.
the structure of a model is

```
public class ServiceSymbols
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ID is required")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<SymbolsDef> SymbolsDef { get; set; }

}
public class SymbolsDef
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}
```

In the view, there are multiple symbol definitions(SymbolsDef) for a service symbol(ServiceSymbols), I used AJAX that can add or remove a symbol definition in terms of a table row. But there is an issue.

if the page load initially with 2 rows. then, I added 3 rows through AJAX, enter value for each one, submit the form. Then, I checked the value in the controller(by adding a break point), only the first 2 SymbolsDef value is what I entered, the rest are the same as the second one.
if the page load initially with 5 rows, and I don't add or remove any, just change the value of each record, then submit. then the value passed to controller don't have this problem.

Here is the part of the submit function:

```
function saveServiceSymbology() {
    var symbolData = $("form#EditSymbols").serialize();
    $.ajax({ url: "/Home/SaveSymbolsDef",
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: symbolData,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Succeed");
        }
    });
}
```

I assume this is kind of binding value to model issue, and I also suspect the serialize function.

Has anyone had this kind of problem? It stuck me for a while, very frustrating.

Here is the action method for add a new row:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0)] // make sure come here each time, do not cathe it.
public ActionResult AddNewSymbolsDef()
{
    return PartialView("_SymbolsDefPartial", new SymbolsDef());
}
```

Here is the save method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveSymbolsDef(ServiceSymbols ServiceSymbols)
{
    //Actions Here
}
```

I didn't write all the actions for SaveSymbolsDef, because when I put a break point in SaveSymbolsDef, and I put the cursor on the "ServiceSymbols", and see all the value from there, the value has already changed, so I don't think it will be the actions problem.

```
Here is the log output when I add a new row:    
<tr>
    <input autocomplete="off" name="SymbolsDef.Index" type="hidden" value="f65560ae-650b-4f6d-ba7e-29db945dc3b0" />
    <td style="display:none">
        <input type="text" id = "fromValue" />
    </td>
    <td style="display:none">
        <input type="text" id = "toValue" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="value" name="SymbolsDef[f65560ae-650b-4f6d-ba7e-29db945dc3b0].value"  type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="label" name="SymbolsDef[f65560ae-650b-4f6d-ba7e-29db945dc3b0].label"  type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <td id="symbolColorPicker">
        <input class="color" id="SymbolsDef_f65560ae-650b-4f6d-ba7e-29db945dc3b0__color" name="SymbolsDef[f65560ae-650b-4f6d-ba7e-29db945dc3b0].color"  type="text" value="" />
        <input id="color" name="SymbolsDef[f65560ae-650b-4f6d-ba7e-29db945dc3b0].value" type="hidden" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="../../Scripts/Images/delete.png" id="DeleteSymbol" title="Delete this row" alt="delete" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick=
        "if ($('#symbolsdiv tr').length > 3) $(this).closest('tr').remove();else alert('This can not be deleted!');reasignSymbol()" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you either place a `debugger;` statement or a `console.log(symbolData)` after `var symbolData = $("form#EditSymbols").serialize();` and check if the new values are part of the serialized data?

Comment: Thanks Francois, I did what you suggested, and it turns out that the value after serialize, which is symbolData, does include all the correct values. but the value showed on controller still has problem.

Comment: can you edit your answer to include your action method?

Comment: @TerryLi: It would be handy if you could post the `console.log()` output of the data when you add a new row as well as the action method. This would make it easier to check if there is anything wrong with the format of the new row data or similar.

Comment: Thanks, Francois, I appended the output to the question. really appreciate it.